# Postfix - Modify header "Message-Id" twice

Tags: email, postfix

I am trying to do both of the following actions. However Postfix only changes the first `Message-Id`. With this example `Precedence: bulk` won't be added because it's at the bottom.

```
/^Message-Id:\s+<(.*?)@www.find.com>/   REPLACE Message-Id: <$1@www.replacewith.com>
/^Message-ID:/i PREPEND Precedence: bulk
```

How can I force postfix to do both of these? Or is it possible to combine them into one check?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to have multiple rules fire for a single header. Wietse Venema's [confirmation](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/postfix-users/conversations/topics/251821):

> As documented, only one rule can fire per line.
>   http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html
>
> As documented, use an external content filter for complex actions.
>   http://www.postfix.org/BUILTIN_FILTER_README.html#limitations

**Aside:**
I'm surprised the `Message-ID` check works, as according to the the `header_checks` [manual page](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html):

> **BUGS**
>   ...
>
> Message headers added by the cleanup(8) daemon itself are excluded from
>          inspection.  Examples  of  such  message  headers  are From:, To:, **Message-ID:**, Date:.

Can you perhaps match on a different header and use that?

Comment: Message-ID does work, it already changes from find.com to replacewith.com and if I put the bulk on top that will work but then the find.com won't.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have just put the second change in front of MIME-Version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `header_checks` lines in the `main.cf` file and then define the check in two different files.

This doesn't scale to 100 headers, but i guess for your problem its useful.